# Dynamic imports at build time Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I statically import a specific package based on configuration at build time?

I am working on a project that has multiple uikits providing the same components in different styles. Each app is configured to use a specific uikit.

```
apps
    app_1
    app_2
packages
    uikit_1
        Component_1
        Component_2
    uikit_2
        Component_1
        Component_2
```

Javascript ES2020 provides dynamic imports:

```
const UIKIT= "uikit_1";

const {Component_1, Component_2} = await import(UIKIT);
```

Howerver, the import is executed in runtime so it could be slower than the static import. Since the configuration is not changing, I would like to statically import the appropriate uikit at build time to improve performance.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You could make separate builds from separate git branches, where you have changed the static imports. But then comes the question: When should you serve which version of the app? Is it based on a user choice / user configurable?

Comment: @ThomasFrank the version is based on the decision at the beginning of the project, it should not be changed later in production but I want to make it changable easily through configuration, just in case I want to try new uikit with the given project, or create a universal template for multiple websites

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [import maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#importing_modules_using_import_maps)?

Comment: If you only have a few versions you could still make a git branch for each. If you're using GitHub you could automate build and deployment (CD) to your server using GitHub Actions. And deploy all versions. Then switch between the versions using different subdomains for each version (set up in your reverse proxy - Nginx?)

Comment: Thanks @ThomasFrank, do you have an example? If I use create-react-app, how could a build select a sepecific uikit without importing other uikits?

Comment: No, I don't have an example - that's more of a high-level "how you could do it". :) Let's see what @Oskar comes up with.

Comment: To give a proper answer, we would have to know: **What environment** are you developing in (e.g. NodeJS, Deno), **and what build tools** are you using? Until then, I can only refer you to the general concept of import maps: Using specifiers in place of URLs/paths, which are specified in so-called import maps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify your build tool. For example, if you are using rollup or vite, you need read configuration in plugin and resolve placeholder in import. Actions would be different for different build tools.

---

example with rollup/plugin-alias

```js
config = { 
 plugins: [
    alias({
      entries: [
       // will replace 'some/:uikit/component1' with 'some/concrete-uikit/component1' if UIKIT_DIRECTORY would be 'concrete-uikit'
       { find: ':uikit', replacement: process.env.UIKIT_DIRECTORY },
     ]
   })
 ]
}
```

---

example with webpack

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      uikit: path.resolve(__dirname, process.env.UIKIT_DIRECTORY),
    },
  },
};
```